# Parameterizing chart sizes for multiple charts using VBA

Tags: vba, charts

I am building a dashboard screen with multiple charts. I declare the charts in their individual build functions like so.

```
Dim chartGallonsComp as ChartObject
Set chartGallonsComp = wsDest.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=45, Width:=240, Height:=180)
```

Since I have multiple charts, I want to pass to the function the .Add method parameters using something like this

```
Dim chartSalesComp As ChartObject, chartGallonsComp As ChartObject
Dim chartCustomers As ChartObject

Dim ws As Worksheet    
ws = Sheets("Dashboard")

Dim aryChartOneDimensions(), aryChartTwoDimensions()
Dim aryChartThreeDimensions()

aryChartOneDimensions = Array(0, 45, 240, 180)
aryChartTwoDimensions = Array(240, 45, 240, 180)
aryChartThreeDimensions = Array(480, 45, 240, 180)

With ws
    Set chartGallonsComp = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=aryChartOneDimensions(1), Top:=aryChartOneDimensions(2),
                                        Width:=aryChartOneDimensions(3),
                                        , Height:=aryChartOneDimensions(4))
End With
```

I'm sure this is doable, I just can't get the syntax right. I've tried a number of ways including formula syntax

```
Left:="=aryChartOneDimensions(1)"
```

but none of my attempts have worked. Please enlighten me if this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set chartGallonsComp = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=aryChartOneDimensions(0), _
                                           Top:=aryChartOneDimensions(1), _
                                           Width:=aryChartOneDimensions(2), _
                                           Height:=aryChartOneDimensions(3))
```

Remember arrays are by default zero-based, not one-based (unless you include `Option Base 1` at the top of your modules, and I don't think that's a good practice)

Comment: yep, been using C# now for too long, a little rusty going back to vba for this spreadsheet. That does work. So to pass that array in a function?... SomeFunction(ByRef ary() as integer)

Comment: @TimWilliams...it didn't like integer but variant works